# semidirect product $\Bbb Z/4 \Bbb Z \rtimes \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Describe all semidirect products $\Bbb Z/4 \Bbb Z \rtimes \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$.

What the litterature says about this question: There is no such semidirect product because there is no non trivial morphisme from $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$ to $(\Bbb Z/4 \Bbb Z)^*$.

Is the simple fact $\Bbb Z/4 \Bbb Z \cap \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z = \{0,1\} \neq \{0\}$ a good argument for the non existence of such product? Or is it wrong to say that $\{1\} \in \Bbb Z/4 \Bbb Z \cap \Bbb Z/2$ because $\{1\}$ has different orders in the same group?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That intersection doesn't make sense, and even if it did it wouldn't tell you about the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, which is what you really need to look at.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write "there is no such semidirect product". That's not true, because we always have the trivial semidirect product, namely the direct product, that is $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) \times (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$.

In order to search for more semidirect products, let's determine the automorphism group $A$ of $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$.

$\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ is the cyclic group of order 4. We can write its elements as 0, 1, 2, 3, where the group operation is addition mod 4.

From this, we see that $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ has two generators, namely 1 and 3.

Since $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ is generated by 1, any endomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ is determined by its image $\varphi(1)$ of 1.

And conversely, for any $g \in \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$, the assignment $1 \mapsto g$ defines an endomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$  with $\varphi(1) = g$. This has to do with the fact that the order of $g$ is a divisor of 4 (the group order).

Also, it's "easy to see" that the endomorphism $\varphi$ is an automorphism iff $\varphi(1)$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$.

Since $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ has two generators (1 and 3, see above), we have two automorphisms, namely $\varphi_1$ determined by $\varphi_1(1) = 1$, and $\varphi_3$ determined by $\varphi_3(1) = 3$.

Now, it's "easy to see" that $\varphi_1$ is the identity map, and "almost as easy to see" that $\varphi_3$ has order 2, that is $\varphi_3 \circ \varphi_3 = \varphi_1$.

But this means that the automorphism group $A$ of $\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$ is the cyclic group of order 2, generated by $\varphi_3$.

Now, because $A$ and $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ are so "simple" (each consists of only two elements, in fact they are isomorphic), there are only two homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ into $A$. Let's write $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z = \{ 0, 1 \}$ with addition mod 2 as group operation. Then $1$ is the generator of $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$, and we have the homomorphisms $\alpha_1: (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) \rightarrow A, 1 \mapsto \varphi_1$ and $\alpha_3: (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) \rightarrow A, 1 \mapsto \varphi_3$.

$\alpha_1$ is trivial and leads to the trivial semidirect product $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) \times (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$.

$\alpha_3$ is nontrivial and leads to the only other (necessarily nontrivial) semidirect product $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) \rtimes (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$.

So we found that there are two semidirect products $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) \rtimes (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$, one trivial and one nontrivial.

You also write $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) \cap (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) = \{0, 1 \}$.
That's not correct, because without further context (for example both groups embedded into a larger group), $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z)$ and $(\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$ are different things and have empty intersection.

For example, it *is* true that, if we write $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) = \{0, 1, 2, 3 \}$ as above, then the subset $\{0, 2 \}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$ (check that), and thus we can write $(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) \cap (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) = \{0, 2 \}$.

But in general, if we write both groups as sets of residues mod 4 and 2, respectively, then we have
$$
(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) = \{0_4, 1_4, 2_4, 3_4 \}
$$
and
$$
(\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) = \{0_2, 1_2 \}
$$
where I have written the modulus as subscript.
"Of course", $0_4 \neq 0_2$ and $1_4 \neq 1_2$, and thus
$$
(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) \cap (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) = \emptyset,
$$
and *not*
$$
(\mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z) \cap (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z) = \{ 0, 1 \} \quad \leftarrow\ WARNING:\ THAT'S\ WRONG.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your thourough answer.